# Select a list of numbers and any nuber that starts with 4 in sql

Tags: sql

this is my first post here at SOF.  I have searched but didn't find anything that related to this.

I have a column `JobNumber` in table `Job` that I need to find a specific list of jobs and any job that starts with the number 4.  The job number can be five numbers, "16545", or six numbers, "117002".

I have tried to use IN and Left like below but cannot come up with the correct syntax for this.

```
WHERE  
dbo].[Job].[JobNumber] IN ('14049', '15393', '15435', '16158', '16224', '16494', '16545', '16562', '16616', '16683')
and Left([JobNumber],1) IN ('4')
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text and also tag the  DBMS you are using like SQLServer/Oracle/Mysql.

Comment: you  can see the link referenced to know on , how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM Job
 WHERE JobNumber LIKE '4%'
```

Comment: Not all DBMS will allow you to compare apples (numbers) and oranges (strings)

Comment: Wouldn't this just return only job numbers that start with the number 4?  How do I get this and the list of specific job numbers at the same time?

Comment: You have to do UNION ALL

Comment: SELECT *
  FROM Job
 WHERE JobNumber LIKE '4%' Union All [dbo].[Job].[JobNumber] IN ('14049', '15393', '15435', '16158', '16224', '16494', '16545', '16562', '16616', '16683')

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Job].[JobNumber]
WHERE [JobNumber] LIKE '4%';
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just return only job numbers that start with the number 4? How do I get this and the list of specific job numbers at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

if field is varchar (or text based) you can do it with left

```
where left(JobNumber,1) = '4'
```

with other options, answers of @Teja or @Biswabid are correct. Like supports comodin, **%** is very util.

Comment: Wouldn't this just return only job numbers that start with the number 4? How do I get this and the list of specific job numbers at the same time?

Comment: with `in` keyword!. if you use ` and jobnumber in ('number','number') ` only works with a number that starts with 4. In your initial list number nothing starts with 4.

Comment: WHERE  
dbo].[Job].[JobNumber] IN ('14049', '15393', '15435', '16158', '16224', '16494', '16545', '16562', '16616', '16683') --This is the list of specific numbers
and Left([JobNumber],1) IN ('4') -- This is how I tried to have the just job numbers with first number 4

Comment: this returns 0! all starts with 1, not 4.

Comment: I am sorry I am not explaining correctly.  The column will contain many more jobs than the list I have.  The list is just specific job numbers that I need from the column as well as all jobs that start with 4. I can get the list of jobs filtered, and I can get all the jobs that start with 4.  I cant get both at the same time.  I hope this didn't confuse anyone more.

Comment: yes, you can get both at he same time.
WHERE [dbo].[Job].[JobNumber] IN ('14049', '15393', '15435', '16158', '16224', '16494', '16545', '16562', '16616', '16683', 'all yours' ) and Left([JobNumber],1) = '4'

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo.  Simple fix from using = instead of IN.